Python requests: how to get the client port used *before* sending a request?
I'm trying to debug an apparently low level intermittent ConnectionError (likely happening at the TCP layer).
For this I've built a multiprocessed program spamming a remote site and catching the relevant error, and am monitoring the traffic via wireshark with the goal of capturing a full faulty TCP conversation.
It's difficult to match an error with a specific TCP conversation in wireshark as there's a really high throughput (that error is very infrequent so I need a lot of them to see it happen once!), so I'd like to record the client side port used in the connection for each request (or at least for failing ones) so I can log this when there's an error and find the culprit TCP stream.
This solution using socket.fromfd was the closest I found, except of course it doesn't work here because the exception happens while making the request so r doesn't exist in case of error and I can't access the fd.
Is there some way to get/create the socket before sending the request so I can know which client port will be used? Or some hook maybe in urllib3 after the socket creation but before the TCP conversation starts, where I can access/log it?

Your question is about using WireShark and then takes a sharp 180 to talk about a really specific Python problem which doesn't really seem directly related. If you're just asking for other tools / frameworks, your question is likely to get closed on account of asking for recommendations. What is your question here? Are you stuck on a specific problem, and can you share some code that illustrates it?

The question is not about using wireshark... I'm asking a specific python question, which is in the title, and more detailed in the last paragraph. The context above is to help responders understand what I'm trying to do with this as it limits the possible solutions.

Why use requests or urllib3 if you're only interested in when the connection is failing (as opposed to something going wrong during the HTTP protocol)? Just use the low-level socket library.

A client port is not allocated until you connect to a remote system. There's no way to know that without establishing a connection. If you need to know your local port in advance, bind() to a specific port instead of using a random one. But if your goal is simply to "to record the client side port used in the connection for each request", why do you need to do this "before the TCP conversation starts"? Why not just log the port after connecting?

We see this bug intermittently in production, and it's hard to reproduce (I have to leave things running for hours to hopefully capture a couple exceptions), and I don't know exactly where it is happening - there's a possibility it's actually an issue in python / network stack... that's why I try to 1) keep the client code as close as possible to what we have in prod (using requests/urllib3) and 2) capture these details of the socket so I can find the packets in the trace if they're there but also validate that they're not there in case it's a python / network stack issue...

@larsks so yeah I'll try to use urllib3 so I can control more precisely the connection like you suggest, and first connect, then log the port, then send the request.. but of course if an exception is thrown in the .connect() call, I'm going to face the same issue again of not being able to find the packets in the trace as I won't know the port, so I can't determine whether it's the TCP connection getting killed early or python not even starting it :/
